# Unable to render material/texture using the script

Tags: python, rendering, texturing, materials

I am new to blender and trying to render [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bcqI3WIjNvBgAYVraqunvoVSRJc1GcEf/view?usp=sharing). Trying to render using script gives a very different result (everything purple) as compared to what I see in Blender GUI. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the script I am using

```
import os
import bpy

bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath="materials.blend")

VIEWS = 1
RESOLUTION = 200
RESULTS_PATH = '.'
DEPTH_SCALE = 1.4
COLOR_DEPTH = 8
FORMAT = 'PNG'
RANDOM_VIEWS = True
UPPER_VIEWS = True
CIRCLE_FIXED_START = (.3, 0, 0)

fp = bpy.path.abspath(f"//{RESULTS_PATH}")
if not os.path.exists(fp):
    os.makedirs(fp)

# Render Optimizations
bpy.context.scene.render.use_persistent_data = True

# Set up rendering of depth map.
bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
links = tree.links

# Add passes for additionally dumping albedo and normals.
# bpy.context.scene.view_layers["RenderLayer"].use_pass_normal = True
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = str(FORMAT)
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_depth = str(COLOR_DEPTH)

# Background
bpy.context.scene.render.dither_intensity = 0.0
bpy.context.scene.render.film_transparent = True

# Create collection for objects not to render with background
objs = [ob for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects if ob.type in ('EMPTY') and 'Empty' in ob.name]
bpy.ops.object.delete({"selected_objects": objs})

def parent_obj_to_camera(b_camera):
    origin = (0, 0, 0)
    b_empty = bpy.data.objects.new("Empty", None)
    b_empty.location = origin
    b_camera.parent = b_empty  # setup parenting

    scn = bpy.context.scene
    scn.collection.objects.link(b_empty)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = b_empty
    # scn.objects.active = b_empty
    return b_empty

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.render.resolution_x = RESOLUTION
scene.render.resolution_y = RESOLUTION
scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100

cam = scene.objects['Camera']
cam.location = (0, 4.0, 0.5)
cam_constraint = cam.constraints.new(type='TRACK_TO')
cam_constraint.track_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
cam_constraint.up_axis = 'UP_Y'
b_empty = parent_obj_to_camera(cam)
cam_constraint.target = b_empty

b_empty.rotation_euler = CIRCLE_FIXED_START
scene.render.image_settings.file_format = FORMAT
scene.render.filepath = fp + '/r_0'
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)  # render still
```

Output of `blender --background --python script.py`

[image]

Screenshot of Blender GUI

[image]

Comment: Looks like you don't have any HDRI map for the World shader. Use one.

Comment: @Carlo - Why do I need a world shader? I am not concerned with background or anything, it is the material of the spheres that is not getting rendered

Comment: You are using a script to render the scene, so all the scenes settings are applied, world shader included. I don't see any line of codes changing that. Who set up the file used a world shader with a texture that you are missing. The file is "forest.exr". You can just get rid of the shader if you don't need it, but if you don't, it will use what is currently defined.

Comment: @Carlo - Got it. Thanks a lot. This was very helpful

Comment: I'm glad it was useful.